# Why does my range extender disconnect from the router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've got a Motorola router in my living room
and this [range extender](https://www.takealot.com/tp-link-300mbps-wireless-range-extender/PLID32580079) in the middle of the house because the router's signal won't reach my room.
The problem is, on occasions the range extender seems to disconnect from the router, and the only solution is to restart the extender, but it doesn't affect the router.

The Wi-Fi from the extender is still there, but it can't connect to the Internet. This is so frustrating! Imagine trying to watch a movie on Netflix but having to go to restart the range extender within half an hour or so because the Wi-Fi is down!

Did this happen to anyone before? 
Do you think is the router's problem or the range extender?

Comment: If you are rebooting the range extender to get things working again, then it would be an issue with the range extender. You should probably contact the manufacturer of the device and troubleshoot with them. There are also a lot of factors that affect this, such as range from router to range extender, distance from range extender to end devices, how many walls the wifi connection has to pass through, are there obstacles directly around the router or range extender, is the range extender faulty, etc. The manufacturer may be able to assist better as they will know issues/bugs with the device.

Answer (score 0):

You answered yourself for the most part.

> only solution is to restart the extender, but it doesn't affect the router

Since you don't have to touch the router, it points to the extender. I would recommend trying to set a static IP on the extender.

Wi-fi can be really fickle about connections, so the more data you have the better.

Start with static IP, then move the extender closer. Wi-fi signal analyzers, which you can install on your phone, will help with seeing if there is a signal issue.